# WinForm Textbox with decimal number validation

Tags: winforms, textbox

How do you check if a user put a dot or comma in the textbox in my decimal number input, and how do I get the message that the error is in the lab if the input is incorrect when using a WinForm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't stated which language you are using.
Is this what you're looking for?

> c#

```
if (textBox1.Text.Contains(".") || textBox1.Text.Contains(","))
   {
       MyLabel1.Text = "Textbox Contains . or ,";
   }
```

You can just change the "MyLabel1.Text" to whatever your Label is called.

Comment: To use C#
I need this for 4 textbox and the error message appears in the label when the user incorrectly places a point or a slash when I enter the decimal number

lblMsgError
txtPrice
txtTransport
txtTax
txtRetail

Comment: I've updated the reply. Please mark up if this helped.

Comment: If this is ok, I will only show the warning message in the label

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the [NumericUpDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown?view=netframework-2.0) control instead of a textbox?

It supports decimal numbers and thousands separator and can be constrained to display only integers. You can set a maximum and minimum values so you don't have to do any validation on what the user enters in to it.